# How to Calculate Precision, Recall, and F1 for Entity Prediction

Tags: python, dataframe, entity, prediction, precision-recall

I used an Entity Linking Model from [Github](https://github.com/facebookresearch/BLINK) to predict a set of documents. Since they do not actually explain how to calculate precision, recall, and F1. So I created a dataframe by using the actual tag and predict tag from the testing data.

```
 Actual           Predict
security          security
london             london
  UK                 US
  :                   :
  :                   :
domain              menu
sushi               soso
tom                jerry
```

I am wondering based on this, will I be able to calculate the precision, recall, and f1 on my own and if I can, how can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have the value of y_test
then you may have y_pred according with your prediction.

Calculating the precision, recall, and fscore are able using these library
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score

calculate metrics

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred)
recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred)
f1_score = f1_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

i got it from
https://machinelearningmastery.com/precision-recall-and-f-measure-for-imbalanced-classification/
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-calculate-precision-recall-f1-and-more-for-deep-learning-models/

The precision of a class define how trustable is the result when the model answer that a point belongs to that class. The recall of a class expresses how well the model is able to detect that class. Ability to derect class is related to the number of training data for each class. If there are imbalanced number of data for each class, then model will not be sensitive to detect some class with the low number. The F1 score of a class is given by the harmonic mean of precision and recall (2×precision×recall / (precision + recall)), it combines precision and recall of a class in one metric.

Balancing the class using resampling methods like undersampler or oversampler smote, may help to increase recall and f1 score

Comment: Yes, I tried this before. But I got a perfect precision score, which I think is very weird. So I am just curious will there be any other ways to do it

Comment: There could some reason,

Comment: you're welcome, good luck